# OperationalError at /admin/Master/profile/ no such table: Master_profile

Tags: django

When I click on Users in admin site, it is showing errors. I am not getting points here.
Also I did migrations, but it is not working.
Please help me out what to do here.

**Errors:**

```
OperationalError at /admin/Master/profile/
no such table: Master_profile
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/Master/profile/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: Master_profile
Exception Location: C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 477, in execute
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['E:\\Project\\S3_project',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Manoj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Wed, 27 Apr 2022 06:36:44 +0000
```

**models.py:**

```
class Profile(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200,null=False)
    contact_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)
    ut=(('Admin','Admin'),('Operator','Operator'),('Ticket generator User','Ticket generator User'),('Inspector','Inspector'),('User 80','User 80'),('Final Inspection','Final Inspection'),('Maintenance','Maintenance'),('Ticket Admin','Ticket Admin'),)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, choices=ut)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} profile'
```

**admin.py:**

```
admin.site.register(Profile)
```

Templates:

**user_show.html:**

```
{% for user in users %}  
            <tr>  
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>  
            <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>   
            <td>{{ user.user_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.password }}</td>
            <td><a href="/Master/user_edit/{{user.id}}"><span style="color:brown;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></p></td>
            <td><a href="/Master/user_delete/{{user.id}}"><span style="color:brown;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></p></td>  
            </tr>  
        {% endfor %}
```

**views.py:**

```
def user_index(request):  
    users = Profile.objects.all()  
    return render(request,"Master/user_show.html",{'users':users})
```

Comment: I would run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again. If nothing happens then try `manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

Comment: I tried this also but showing same error

Comment: It seems that `Profile` model in not in DB. Do you recently modified something there? In the worst case you will need to drop db, delete all migrations and create them again

Comment: I have deleted migrations and created again but showing same error

Comment: @ManojTolagekar  Have you deleted the database file and tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had Encountered a similar error when I was starting with Django,Which I solved by removing the existing database (db.sqlite3) and deleting the migrations folders of the app. And then re-running `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`

Also check if your app is registered in the `settings.py`

Comment: I have deleted migrations and re-created but showing same error

Comment: @ManojTolagekar Have you deleted the database file and tried?

Comment: there should be a file (db.sqlite3) in your project folder. Delete that and try re-running the migrations

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues since yesterday, I've been struggling with it big time.

I tried to run:

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

After deleting my `db.sqlite3` file, and everything is back to normal -
Bartosz Stasiak